How to send pagination link to laravel/livewire nested component?
I have built a table component in livewire. I can pass all the parameters from my main model component to the table component and everything works fine except the pagination links.
Here is the error:
Property type not supported in Livewire for property: [{"current_page":1,"data":[{"id":27,.......
.......}],"first_page_url":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/employees?employee_page=1","from":1,"last_page":2,"last_page_url":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/employees?employee_page=2","links":[{"url":null,"label":"&laquo; Previous","active":false},{"url":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/employees?employee_page=1","label":"1","active":true},{"url":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/employees?employee_page=2","label":"2","active":false},{"url":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/employees?employee_page=2","label":"Next &raquo;","active":false}],"next_page_url":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/employees?employee_page=2","path":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/employees","per_page":20,"prev_page_url":null,"to":20,"total":27}]

Here is my code in main component:
 @livewire('includes.dynamicdatatable.table', [
                            'table' => $table,
                            'table_tabs_buttons' => $this->table_tabs_buttons,
                            'table_filter_rows' => $this->table_filter_rows,
                            'table_rows' => $this->table_rows,
                            'table_pagination_infos' => $this->tablePaginationInfos,
                            'model' => $this->employees,
                        ])

This is the code in nested component:
<div class="col-4">
            {{ $this->model->links() }}
</div>

This is the code in nested component mount method:
public function mount($table, $table_tabs_buttons, $table_filter_rows, $table_rows, $table_pagination_infos, $model)
    {
        $this->initial_table = $table;
        $this->table = $table;
        $this->table_tabs_buttons = $table_tabs_buttons;
        $this->table_filter_rows = $table_filter_rows;
        $this->table_rows = $table_rows;
        $this->table_pagination_infos = $table_pagination_infos;
        $this->model = $model;
    }

How can I pass the pagination links to my nested component properly?
